# How to print formatted JSON value in Ballerina

Tags: json, format, pretty-print, ballerina

Please run the following example code.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    json j = {"id": 1, "name": "John", "address": {"city": "New York", "country": "USA"}};
    io:println(j);
}
```

Here `j` is printed in the console without formatting as shown below.

```
{"id":1,"name":"John","address":{"city":"New York","country":"USA"}}
```

What is the recommended way to print formatted JSON value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`thisarug/prettify`](https://central.ballerina.io/thisarug/prettify/1.0.0) package to pretty print a JSON value.

```
import ballerina/io;
import thisarug/prettify;

public function main() {
    json j = {"id": 1, "name": "John", "address": {"city": "New York", "country": "USA"}};
    io:println(prettify:prettify(j));
}
```

This code will print the following:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "address": {
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```